# Sum of biggest values

Tags: ocaml

I am pretty sure the problem is trivial. Unfortunately, I am new to Ocaml programming, then I am looking in the wrong direction, most likely.

I want to create a function `sum_largest_values` that takes the n biggest values between the inputs and sums them.

My best attempt so far:

```
utop # let sum_largest_values (x:int)(y:int) = 
if (x > y) || (y > x) then ((+) x y)
else 
0;;
```

The problem rises when I try to add a third value:

```
utop # let sum_largest_values (x:int)(y:int)(z:int) = 
if (x > y > z) || (y > x > z) then ((+) x y)
else 
0;;
```

I cannot define such a function:

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was 
expected of type bool
```

Why the third value `z` makes the function unusable?

Comment: divide and conquer!  Functional programming encourages composition, i.e. find largest n --> sum

Comment: I don't see how either version meets your requirement; surely if the specification is "sums the n largest values" then n must be a parameter to the function, yet I do not see it anywhere.  **Start by getting the function signature correct** before you worry about the body.  If your problem is to sum the n largest elements of a list of things then the signature has to include a *list* and a *count*.  Get that right, and make the method return a *wrong* value, and now you have something you can at least start to test while you get the body correct.

Comment: Also, why is the method called `sumsqr` instead of `sum_largest_values` if that's what it does?

Comment: @EricLippert thank you for your suggestions, I am trying to apply them right now. The name remained from a previous experiment. Now it should be more adequate.

Comment: I may be totally misunderstanding your question, but I attempted to answer below. Let me know if that helps, or I can try to understand the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you are wanting to take as input two `int list` and one `int` argument, taking the largest `n` values of the concatenation of the two `int lists` and summing them?

```
(* first, make an inner function to store running total *)
let rec sum_largest_inner l n acc =
  match n with
      0 -> acc
    | x -> match l with
               [] -> 0
             | h :: t -> sum_largest_inner t (x-1) (h+acc)
```

What that function is doing, is taking a single `int list` and summing the first `n` values and storing it in `acc`. This inner function is assuming that the `int list` is already sorted in descending order, so we want to make sure to pass in a valid `int list`.

```
let sum_largest_values x y n =
  let z = List.sort compare (x @ y) in
  sum_largest_inner (List.rev z) n 0
```

In this function, we append `y` to `x` and sort the resulting list `z` in descending order, then pass the resulting `int list` to our inner function from above. This function can easily be modified to add a third, fourth, etc. number of lists, which I will leave to you as an exercise :)

This code also doesn't do any safety checking to make sure you pass valid inputs, it assumes that everything is kosher coming in.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to directly compare 3 or more numbers you cannot do it like that:

```
# 1<2<3;;
File "", line 1, characters 4-5:
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type bool
```

You can build more complex conditions:

```
# (1<2) && (2<3);;
- : bool = true
# ((1<2) && (2<3)) || ((3<4) && (4<5));;
- : bool = true
```

But getting back to the original problem

> sumsqr that takes the n biggest values between the inputs and sums them

You can try to put the numbers in the array or list, sort the list, take n first elements of the sorted list and sum them up.